# FTP to FTP - a running web site to a new VPS

Tags: ftp, hosting

I have a running web site, which get updated quite frequently with user's input, and because of the amount of people servicing, I decided to move to a more dedicated solution, so I got myself a VPS, Now, I need to transfer the content of the websites, the company I host with (hostgator), allows that, but I need a better solution, as they'll do it only for one time, and while the nameservers will be updated, I need to keep the other server sync'd.

So I thought about something like FTP to FTP, but I don't know any software which does that,
Help, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you use dynamic web pages, you will have to take your website down for some time while moving it.

You're probably looking for [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) for moving your files. [Supported clients are listed on wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_FTP_client_software#Protocol_support)

If you've got a database, dump it and import it again on your new machine. Your hoster probably will offer you phpMyAdmin for this purpose.

If you want to test if everything works fine, do a complete test of the procedure before switching servers without changing DNS records. Make notes to be able to reproduce the steps you did.

For being able to switch your domain to your new VPS quickly, set TTL of the DNS entries to some short timespan like 5 or 10 minutes a day or two before starting moving the server. If everything went fine, increase it to a day or such to avoid DNS overhead.

Comment: what kind of FXP clients you know? I tried using filerush - no go

Comment: Never used it myself. Forgot the way I had used: I guess you will have shell access to your VPS, just pull the data from there. Use midnight commander if you don't get along with ftp command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the share feature of [AutoFileMove](http://www.autofilemove.com/) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YksMUNmcv4
http://www.autofilemove.com/Support/Features#sharing